# How to use conf file in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to avoid *hard coding* by just including `conf.php` which will have the *variables/values* that I'll be needing.

How can I achieve this?

Here's my code for **conf.php**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "tiger","tiger") or die (mysql_error ());
mysql_select_db("theaterdb") or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Other ***PHP*** pages are coded like this:

```
$q = strtolower(trim($_GET["q"]));

try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=theaterdb;host=localhost','tiger','tiger');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$sql = 'SELECT address FROM theater WHERE LOWER(theater_name) = :q';

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindValue(':q', $q);
$sth->execute();
```

Instead of this line:

```
dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=theaterdb;host=localhost','tiger','tiger');
```

I want to use the `conf.php` file. How will I be able to do this?

Comment: Are you asking use how to put a line declaring a global PDO object into a conf file to replace the globally configured `mysql_connect()` connection?

Comment: `PDO` and `mysql_connect` don't work with each other

Comment: @MikeBrant i just want to replace the try block with conf.php file

Comment: `catch (PDOException $e)` <- Why is everyone doing this lately?!

Comment: @Mithuncj Well then just put that code in conf.php.

Answer (score 0):

//Include conf.php in every other pages

conf.php

```
<?php
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=theaterdb;host=localhost','tiger','tiger');
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

other_page.php

```
<?php
    include("conf.php");

    $q = strtolower(trim($_GET["q"]));

    $sql = 'SELECT address FROM theater WHERE LOWER(theater_name) = :q';

    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->bindValue(':q', $q);
    $sth->execute();

?>
```